# mdadm does not automount raid0 disks under /media/storage

Tags: mount, raid, mdadm, fdisk

I've beat my head against this issue all night and I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

I've recently installed Linux Mint 17.3 Mate to replace my Windows 10 machine and after some tinkering I've got stuff working finally.

The only issue I have is getting the raid0 disks to automount at boot.

If I want to mount the disks I have to open terminal and enter:

```
Nebuchadnezzar ~ # mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: Container /dev/md126 has been assembled with 2 drives
```

I can then use the drives normally for the most part. I still can't seem to access them via /media/storage though. Any way that I can setup mdadm to automount this raid array for me during bootup at /media/storage?

FDISK -L Output:

```
Nebuchadnezzar ~ # fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 480.1 GB, 480103981056 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 58369 cylinders, total 937703088 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0003bd2e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   937701375   468599809    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760   937701375   468599808   8e  Linux LVM

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 242251 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdc doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/mint--vg-root: 445.5 GB, 445481222144 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 54160 cylinders, total 870080512 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/mint--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap_1: 34.3 GB, 34313601024 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 4171 cylinders, total 67018752 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
/etc/fstab

Nebuchadnezzar ~ # cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=5c4853b8-7c35-421e-81d2-6c45ac712770 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=5c4853b8-7c35-421e-81d2-6c45ac712770   /boot   ext2    defaults    02

#Raid Addon
/dev/md126 /media/storage ext4 defaults,nobootwait 0 0
```

/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf

```
Nebuchadnezzar ~ # cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf 
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

DEVICE partitions

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root


ARRAY /dev/md126 UUID=d6942994:2c24623b:07cd5adc:651ba0ae
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: is there some error in `/var/log/messages` related to `fstab` or `mdadm` or `md` or `mount`... they could be useful to detect where is the problem.